# How to make docker container running continuously?

Tags: python, docker, shell, docker-compose

I have a Docker image that is actually a server for a device. It is started from a Python script, and I made .sh to run it. However, whenever I run it, it says that it is executed and it ends (server exited with code 0). The only way I made it work is via docker-compose when I run it as detached container, then enter the container via bin/bash and execute the run script (beforementioned .sh) from it manually, then exit the container.

After that everything works as intended, but the issue arises when the server is rebooted. I have to do it manually all over again.

Did anyone else experience anything similar? If yes how can I fix this?

File that starts server (start.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
python source/server/main.pyc &
python source/server/main_socket.pyc &
python source/server/main_monitor_server.pyc &
python source/server/main_status_server.pyc &
python source/server/main_events_server.pyc &
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN mkdir -p /home/server

COPY server /home/server/

EXPOSE 8854

CMD [ /home/server/start.sh ]
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    tty: yes
    image: deviceserver:latest
    container_name: server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8854:8854"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 3072M
```

Comment: The scripts you run in your containers should log to stdout and not be run as a daemon or background tasks. Are all five of these processes required to be running? If so you should maybe think about running a separate container for each process

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, they are all required to be run in the same container, unfortunately. This is something I cannot change.

Comment: You can add `tail -f /dev/null` as the last line in your script. That seems to be a popular way to create a process that doesn't end.

Comment: Why can you not change this? Maybe something like `supervisor` might work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with docker-compose. Your docker container should not return (i.e block) even when launched with a simple `docker run`.

For that your **CMD should run in the foreground**.

I think the issue is that you're `start.sh` returns instead of blocking. Have you tried to remove the last '&' from your script (I'm not familiar with python and what these different processes are)?

Comment: This didn't work either... @Bonana

Comment: even with the syntax change suggested by @David Maze, to add quotes: [ "/home/server/start.sh" ] ?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should run only one process per container.  If you have five separate processes you need to run, you would typically run five separate containers.

The corollaries to this are that the main container command should be a foreground process; but also that you can run multiple containers off of the same image with different commands.  In Compose you can override the `command:` separately for each container.  So, for example, you can specify:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  main:
    image: deviceserver:latest
    command: ./main.py
  socket:
    image: deviceserver:latest
    command: ./main_socket.py
  et: cetera
```

If you're trying to copy-and-paste this exact `docker-compose.yml` file, make sure to set a `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile so that the scripts are in the current directory, make sure the scripts are executable (`chmod +x` in your source repository), and make sure they start with a "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.  You shouldn't need to explicitly say `python` anywhere.

```sh
FROM python:3.9       # not a bare Ubuntu image
WORKDIR /home/server  # creates the directory too
COPY server ./        # don't need to duplicate the directory name here
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8854           # optional, does almost nothing
CMD ["./main.py"]     # valid JSON-array syntax; can be overridden
```

There are two major issues in the setup you show.  The `CMD` is not a syntactically valid JSON array (the command itself is not `"quoted"`) and so Docker will run it as a shell command; `[` is an alias for **test**(1) and will exit immediately.  If you do successfully run the script, the script launches a bunch of background processes and then exits, but since the script is the main container command, that will cause the container to exit as well.  Running a set of single-process containers is generally easier to manage and scale than trying to squeeze multiple processes into a single container.

Answer (score -1):

You can add sleep command in the end of your `start.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
python source/server/main.pyc &
python source/server/main_socket.pyc &
python source/server/main_monitor_server.pyc &
python source/server/main_status_server.pyc &
python source/server/main_events_server.pyc &
while true
do
  sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work, unfortunately.